# Using elixir applications for programs that run only once

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp, elixir-mix

When starting an application the return value needs to be a pid or an error.

Is it possible to use applications for programs that are meant to only run through there processing once. Something like.

```
defmodule MyApp do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    # Do stuff
    {:done, :normal}
  end
end
```

Comment: Applications are for long running programs that need to be robust... if this is meant as an one-off,  like for example a console script, why wouldn't you model it as a script (.exs?). And if it is meant to be robust, why does the Application model trouble you?

Comment: Why do you need an OTP application for it?

Comment: So the answer is to not use an application and make an escript? I'm not exactly sure what makes a correct mix project. perhaps the question is what does a mix project look like for a single run program.

Comment: You probably don't need to change the way mix sets your project up. If you need your app to stop, why not just [Application.stop](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Application.html#stop/1) it when you're done?

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating things @Peter.  What you want is an Elixir script (exs file).  Start with this example:

```
defmodule MyApp do
  def my_test_func do
    IO.puts "Hello world!"
  end
end

MyApp.my_test_func
```

Save that code as `test1.exs`.  Then you can run it from the command prompt via `elixir test1.exs`  What I'm saying is that you don't need a `gen_server` for a simple script.

You can find out more about interacting with the OS in [the `System` docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html) and you can see a bit more on the topic of Elixir scripts here: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/introduction.html#running-scripts